# How can I calculate power of two BigInts/BigUints?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The title says it all. I tried to find something in the Rust docs but the only thing I came across is this function for the BigInt/Biguint structs.

```
pub fn modpow(&self, exponent: &Self, modulus: &Self) -> Self
```

I also found this function in the num::pow but it doesn't help me as my exp is BigInt/BigUint too.

```
pub fn pow<T>(base: T, exp: usize) -> T
```

So, anyone has any idea? I'm thinking that I should use the modpow function somehow, but what do I send for the modulus parameter?

Comment: Use rust-num crate with BigUInt, it's a wrapper, wont overflow with limitations of your runtime. https://github.com/rust-num/num

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the exponent to `usize` and then call `BigUint::pow()`. If the exponent is larger than `usize::MAX`, you won't be able to calculate the power anyway. For example:

```
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn pow(n: BigUint, exp: BigUint) -> BigUint {
    n.pow(exp.try_into().expect("exponent too large for pow()"))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53045b1d2d21b70cee1e655b5969feca)

Comment: There is actually 3 cases you might want to handle where `exp>usize::MAX`, `n=0`, `n=1` and `n=-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try my big_pow function
Note: very large computations may take a long time but they should theoretically execute given enough time to loop through. I haven't ran into any memory allocation failures yet but also have not tested extremely thoroughly.

```
use num_bigint::BigInt;
use num_traits::{cast::FromPrimitive};
fn big_pow(base: BigInt, exp: BigInt) -> BigInt
{
    if exp == BigInt::from_u32(0).unwrap()
    {
        return BigInt::from_u32(1).unwrap();
    }
    let mut answer = base.clone();
    let mut i = BigInt::from_u32(1).unwrap();
    while i < exp
    {
        i = i + BigInt::from_u32(1).unwrap();
        answer = answer * base.clone();
    }
    return answer;
}
```

if you need to use a modulus:

```
use modexp::modexp;
use num_bigint::BigInt;
use num_traits::{cast::FromPrimitive};
pub fn modexp_fast_internal_copy(mut b: BigInt, mut e: BigInt, m: BigInt) -> BigInt
{
    let mut result = BigInt::from_u64(1).unwrap();
    let big1 = BigInt::from_u64(1).unwrap();
    let big2 = BigInt::from_u64(2).unwrap();
    while e > BigInt::from_u64(0).unwrap()
    {
        if e.clone() % big2.clone() == big1
        {
            result = (result.clone() * b.clone()) % m.clone();
        }
        b = (b.clone() * b.clone()) % m.clone();
        e = e.clone() / 2.clone();
    }
    result % m
}
```

I modified the 2nd function from this original source:
https://docs.rs/crate/modexp/0.2.2/source/src/lib.rs